# What is the difference of “a troubling cut to Social Security” from “a troubling cut of Social Security”?

Tags: prepositions

The Home page of today's (April 11) New York Times carries an article titled ‘In the President’s Budget’ written by their Editorial Board, which is followed by the lead copy -

> “The plan for 2014 includes a troubling cut ***to*** Social Security and
>   other better ideas that put Republicans on the spot.”

Though this might be a primitive question, as usual, from a non native English speaker, if I replace the preposition ‘to’ in “a troubling cut to Social Security” with ‘of,’ what difference of meaning would come out from the original line?

Comment: _in_ would probably be more appropriate: "a cut in Social Security".

Comment: The preposition *to* here implies action of one body (agency) against a thing. A cut *in* Social Security sounds arguably more benign than a cut *to* it, or at least less directly involving or specifying an agent that is to perform the cutting. "You have a wound in your chest" attributes no responsibility for the injury, whereas "Karl delivered a wound to your chest" does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *cut of* something generally refers to the portion of a thing that has been cut off or removed (e.g., "a cut of beef"). Thus, *a cut of social security* would refer to the part of social security that has been removed, whatever that might be.

A *cut to* something, meanwhile, refers to the cut (reduction) itself, not the entity that has been cut (sliced) off. *Cut in* would also make sense in this context.

Comment: I should add that I can't think of a situation where *a cut of social security* would sound idiomatic, but I'm not ruling out the possibility.

Comment: Perhaps few are concerned about their cut of social security, but quite many about their cut of Social Security.

Comment: @choster. Shouln't either of the above "their cut of social security" be "their cut to cocial security."?

Comment: @YoichiOishi What I mean is they may not care one whit about social security referring to safety against poverty and cohesion in civil society, but they will invariably care quite a bit about their "cut" from the U.S. Social Security system, meaning their claim to a payout from it — their share, their lot, their lucre, their piece of the action, slice of the pie, taste of the gravy... which by some calculations, absent reforms, would ironically lead to a rather insecure future and a rather disharmonious society.